# Why are my bootstrap nav tabs not aligning to the left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap nav tabs:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="projectTabStrip" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" id="projectDetailsTab">
            <a class="nav-link">Project Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="projectStatusTab">
            <a class=nav-link>Status</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="projectDocumentsTab">
            <a class=nav-link>Documents</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I removed all of the `href` tags for brevity and to make it easier to read.
My problem is that the tabs are displaying like this:
[image: nav-tabs issue]
By default, the tabs should be on the left side of the page, correct? What is causing this issue?

My goal is to get the tabs to align to the left side of the page, something like this:[image: nav-tabs correct]

Comment: First - what exact version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided it would appear that your `container` is the problem.  The `container` element applies a fixed width to everything within it, centering itself to the viewport.

The code that you have provided doesn't suggest that this component is required, but given that you've provided a minimal example you may expect unforeseen issues with its removal.

Answer (score 1):

As mister @Robert already wrote, the align left problem caused by `.container` div. Although lets write your code more correct. You misses `.active` class in first `li a`. And a `href` attribute you will need anyway. Minimal it should be `href='#'` for the correct work of Bootstrap tabs.

```
<div class="any-class-not-container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="projectTabStrip" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" id="projectDetailsTab">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Project Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="projectStatusTab">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Status</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="projectDocumentsTab">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Documents</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

More about Nav tabs in Bootstrap 4 you can read here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior